# daylight saving adjustment

Tags: php, perl, dst

i am really aware about daylight saving ,

just couple of weeks back only, i thinking about the daylight saving,

How to set date and time when Daylight start and how much we hour we should add and how much

hours we subtract and when should we do this,

What are that EDT, EST and all,

i am totally struck with this. what are formula behind in this?

is there any simple explanation there,

Why india does not have DST,

is there any connection with word map for day light saving.

Comment: What did you consult to research this?  Even Wikipedia could have answered all these questions.

Comment: but i would expect something diff from wiki, that would be appriciate

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a formula. Different countries implement it as per their own requirements.

Use a look up table to deal with it. Better yet, don't. Any quarter-decent date-time library will handle it for you.

For example, since you have tagged this *perl*, see the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm) module. Specifically the is_dst method.

```
$dt->is_dst()
```

> Returns a boolean indicating whether or not the datetime object is currently in Daylight Saving Time or not.